# error running readLAS() in lidR: 'new_proj_and_gdal' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rgdal'

Tags: gdal, r, las, rgdal, lidr

I've just updated lidR to 3.1.1 and am now unable to load a .las file using `readLAS()`:

```r
las <- lidR::readLAS(paste(sfm_dir,"/","201807XX_Denali_FHM_north_group1_densified_point_cloud_part_2.las",sep=""))
#> Error: 'new_proj_and_gdal' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rgdal'
```

I have not gotten this error with my previous version of lidR (3.0.1) which I just removed to allow for upgrade.

Maybe pertinent additional info:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)
rgdal_1.4-8
raster_3.3-13
sp_1.4-4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of `rgdal` is 1.5-23. Update your packages. `lidR` depends on recent versions of `rgdal`. The `DESCRIPTION` files states it depends on `rgdal (>= 1.4.8)` but it is an error it actually depends on `rgdal (>= 1.5.8)` because `new_proj_and_gdal()` was introduced in 1.5.8